# Lightning component get parameters from app builder

Tags: lightning

Can we pass parameters to lightning component attributes from the app builder ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes you can. That is where we can use design attributes. 
We can have a dynamic lightning component which could be used on multiple objects using design attributes.

Find an example here - http://sfdcmonkey.com/2017/10/03/design-resource-lightning-component/